# Github Actions: Cache Error and end action without fail message

Tags: github, github-actions, git-commit

I have a github action that transforms my Readme from one format to the other and which will then push the new Readme to the repository. For the pushing I have defined this job:

```yaml
  push_readme:
    name: Push new Readme
    needs: generate_readme
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Download readme result from job 1 generate_readme
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: readme
      - name: Commit files
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
          git status
          git add READMEmd.md
          git commit -m "Actions Generated Readme"
      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

The commit returns an error when there is nothing to commit - which happens whenever the readme was not updated in the recent push. This is expected and fine. However, I would like to handle this error properly s.t. the action simply ends when it occurs WITHOUT telling me it failed. Instead I'd like something in the sense of "There is no new README to commit. Ending the action".

Could anyone point me to how to do that? I failed to find the solution yet.

Comment: Is that a typo i.e. `READMEmd.md` in `git add` command?

Comment: @Azeem no, the naming of the file is on purpose.

Comment: Right. You might need to adjust that when copying from my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize Bash and check `git diff` for the `README` file and [set an output parameter](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-output-parameter) with `GITHUB_OUTPUT` for the next step to check if there indeed is a commit.

Here is an example:

```yaml
      - name: Commit files
        id: commit
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
          git status
          if [[ -n $(git diff README.md) ]]; then
            git add README.md
            git commit -m "Actions Generated Readme"
            echo "DONE=true" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
          else
            echo "README is the same. Nothing to commit."
          fi
      - name: Push changes
        if: ${{ steps.commit.DONE }}
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

Comment: I will try this out later, thank you! Had only thought to move the entire thing to bash but this seems a lot nicer. I appreciate it!

Comment: @AnnemarieWittig: You're welcome! IMO, the last push action is redundant. You can simply remove that and add the `git push` command right after the `git commit` in the `if` block.

Comment: you're right, I removed it. Works like a charm, thank you!